# Managing multiple versions of internal (private) NuGet packages

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

Our development team has been fairly small and, until now, all working on a single Visual Studio 2012 solution. We are growing and wanting to create better separation with multiple solutions for different project teams.

However, there are occasions where the code in one solution will want to utilize code from another. We have decided using internal (i.e. private) NuGet packages will be a good way to manage these dependencies.

However, the question has come up on how to deal with multiple versions of the same package that are in different SDLC stages (e.g. Development, QA, Staging, Production, etc.)

Example: If we have these three solutions...

```
CoreStuff
CoolProject1
CoolProject2
```

If working in CoolProject1, and we need to utilize code from CoreStuff, we can add the NuGet package. Presumably this package will be the latest Production (stable) version of CoreStuff.

However, what if a developer working on CoolProject2 is aware of some changes in CoreStuff that are currently in Development and wants to utilize that version?

Not sure if the best approach is to create separate packages for each (seems to require changing your package references back and forth depending on what stage the solution is in) or somehow utilize multiple versions of the same package (not sure if that's easy to manage with NuGet).

Anyone tackle something like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first thing to remember is that NuGet will not automatically update your package references, so if you have already 'linked' your solution to the latest stable package of CoreStuff (say 1.2.2) then there won't be any problems if a newer (unstable) version is provided (assuming that the package you're using doesn't disappear from the package repository). Obviously if you upgrade your package reference then you will get the unstable package.

So the simplest solution is to make sure that you 'link' your project to the stable package by getting it via the NuGet package manager before the other package is released. While the UI only allows you to get the latest version, the Package Manager Console can get any version of a package so you could use that to explicitly provide the version number, e.g.:

```
Install-Package CoreStuff -Version 1.2.2 -Project CoolProject1
```

If that is not a solution then there are several other options to tackle this problem:

- Give the development version a different semantic version that indicates it is a unstable version, e.g. 1.2.3-alpha. In this case CoolProject1 could pull in package CoreStuff.1.2.2 (which should be latest stable version in your repository) and CoolProject2 could pull in CoreStuff.1.2.3-alpha (which would be the latest unstable version).
- Have multiple repositories, e.g. one for stable (released) packages and one for unstable (development) versions. Then you can select your packages from the desired repositories. If you wanted to you could make it so that only your release process can push packages up to the stable repository and your CI build pushes up to the unstable one (so that you always have the latest packages available)
- If the developer of CoolProject2 just wants to develop against the latest version (but will wait to release CoolProject2 until after CoreStuff v.next has been released) then he could potentially create a local package repository (i.e. a directory on his drive) and put the new package of core stuff there. That way other developers won't even see the package.

The most important thing will be to make sure that you don't get CoreStuff.1.2.2 and CoreStuff.v-next in the same repository if CoreStuff.v-next simply has a higher version number, because in that case the NuGet UI won't let you pick v1.2.2 (but the Package Manager Console does!).

If you would want to switch from one package type to another you'd have to do a manual update (which you always have to do when changing to the next package version anyway), but that's not a bad thing given that this forces a developer to at least check that the update of the package doesn't break anything.

Comment: Good answer, pity the OP disappeared without accepting it.